# localorshuffle grouping in storm

Tags: apache-storm

Consider following configuration for a topology:
#spouts: 2
#bolt: 8
#workers: 3

[image]

With this configuration one of the workers won't have spout and If we apply localorshuffle grouping between spout and bolt, does worker-3 bolts receive any tuple ?

Comment: With localOrShuffle grouping, it sends to remote only if no local task is found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not as far as I know. When you use localOrShuffle grouping, you're saying that you want to send to any bolts that are within the same JVM if possible, and only send outside the JVM if there is no appropriate bolt task inside the VM.